# Matlab range - gamma correction

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, range, gamma

Could you tell me how to take a range of an image? I want to do a gamma correction of "cameraman.tif" for pixels in range 0:120 gamma = 1.8, for pixels in range 120:255 gamma = 0.5

But all pixels go to first if statement so I am unable to apply second gamma.

```
a = imread('cameraman.tif');
gamma1 = 2;
gamma2 = 0.5;
N =size(a);
out = zeros(N);
for i=1:N
  for j=1:N
    temp=a(i,j);
    if temp>0&temp<120
       out(i,j)=temp.^2;
    end
    if temp>120&temp<=255
       out(kx,ky)=temp.^0.5;
    end
 end
end
imshow(out)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second `if` statement uses access variables `kx` and `ky`.... I'm assuming you wanted to use `i` and `j`:

```
out(i,j)=temp.^0.5;
```

You also **must** make sure that the intensity is double precision for the square root to work.  Therefore make sure that the intensity read in per location is cast to `double`, then convert back to `uint8` when you're done.  Actually, do the conversion **after** you sweep through the whole image.

```
for i=1:N
  for j=1:N
    temp=double(a(i,j)); % Change
    if temp>0&temp<120
       out(i,j)=temp.^2;
    end
    if temp>120&temp<=255
       out(i,j)=temp.^0.5; % Change
    end
 end
end

out = uint8(out); % Change
```

`kx` and `ky` were set somewhere else in your code and are never changing, so this means that if and when the second `if` statement does happen, the setting of the gamma only happens at one spot only defined at `kx` and `ky`.  My advice to you would be to write an actual **function** so that you aren't cross-contaminating variables in different workspaces.  Encompassing this in a function would have given you an error immediately telling you that `kx` and `ky` are not defined.

BTW, I would rather you do this more efficiently without loops.  You can very easily perform the same operations vectorized.  However, this requires that you convert the image to `double` as the default type is `uint8` for the Cameraman image.  Therefore, use `double`  to convert an image to `double`, do the gamma correction, then convert back using `uint8`:

```
a = double(imread('cameraman.tif'));
out = zeros(size(a));
out(a > 0 & a < 120) = a(a > 0 & a < 120).^2;
out(a >= 120 & a <= 255) = a((a >= 120 & a <= 255).^0.5;
out = uint8(out);
```

The first and second line of code are of course familiar. The third line of code finds a `logical` mask where we search for intensities between 0 and 120 exclusive.  Once we find those values, we use the same logical mask to index into the original image and only access those values, square each value and set them in the same spatial locations at the output.  The same can be said for the last line of code where you're searching between 120 and 255 but you are taking the square root instead.  We finally convert to `uint8` for display.

Comment: And, as I am sure you are editing in right now, it's better done vectorized :-)

Comment: @LuisMendo :D:D:D lol... waiting for the other shoe to drop eh?

Comment: Very nice, I didn't know that expression!

Comment: @LuisMendo :D... yes, waiting for the other shoe to drop means that some event has occurred or some fact has been explained to you but not fully.... as soon as you find out what the end gives you, that's waiting for the other shoe to drop.

Comment: It looks good but matlab gives me error " Integers can only be raised to positive integral powers."

Comment: @Knight You have to convert your image to `double`.  I'll change my answer.

Comment: Ok, but now out(a >= 120 & a <= 255) = a((a >= 120 & a <= 255).^0.5; don't seem to do anything :)

Comment: @Knight got it. Try it now.  I forgot that you specified the search range in `uint8` when `im2double` converts the image to `[0,1]`. I just used manual casting instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you are awesome :D

Comment: @Knight :D no problem at all.  BTW, I corrected your original code so you can see where things went wrong... but totally go vectorized. You won't be sorry!